# How to change the default line length for od and hexdump

Tags: command-line, utilities, binary, od

Is there any way to change the default line length for the `od` and `hexdump` commands? Can't see anything apropriate in the man pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`od` has the `--width=N` argument, which you can use to choose how many bytes per line, perhaps that's what you're looking for?  `hexdump` has a `-e FORMATSTRING` which has promise, but I've never played too much with it.

Comment: hey thanks for the tip about `width` in `od`, my man pages didn't have that!

Comment: @newenglander as mentioned under SEE ALSO you should also check `info coreutils 'od invocation'`.

Comment: With anything GNU, it's always a good idea to check the info page.  It has much more information.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip, my SEE ALSO only had _hexdump(1), strings(1)_.

Comment: Calling `info coreutils 'od invocation'` on my systems (Mac OS X, FreeBSD) gives me the message `No menu item 'coreutils' in node '(dir)Top'.` But I did try it on Linux and it was indeed more helpful (but then again so was the `man` page on that system).

Comment: @newenglander: The `od` and `hexdump` on MacOSX isn't the GNU version, but BSD.  They're different implementations than the GNU utilities, so no info pages.  Good to hear that the `--width` argument works.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question, but for completeness, here is an example `hexdump` command that prints 8 bytes per line:

```
hexdump -e '8/1 " %02X" "\n"' <file>
```

More information about hexdump format strings can be found at these links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694065/hexdump-how-to-change-number-of-columns
- https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/making-sense-hexdump/

For `od`, use the `--width[=BYTES]` argument that jsbillings mentioned.  Here's the man page for more info:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to make -C | --canonical like but width-wide

```
hexdump -e '"%08_ax " '$(($(tput cols 2> /dev/null || echo $COLUMNS ) / 4 - 4 ))'/1 "%02x " " |" '$(($(tput cols 2> /dev/null || echo $COLUMNS ) / 4 - 4 ))'/1 "%_p" /0 "| \n"'
```

just change '$(($(tput cols 2> /dev/null || echo $COLUMNS ) / 4 - 4 ))' to your value

Comment: Good digging - thanks for this!